# Bootstrap 5 Alert Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

So when I try to put a bootstrap alert into my HTML code, it doesnt show up. Here is my code:

```html
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            text
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
```

(I copied it from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/)

And these are my CSS and JS imports on `<head>`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is how it looks like when I put it inside my code:

[image]

I really don't know how to fix this, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Just copied whatever you wrote in the question into this basic html layout and it worked as expected. Maybe double check to see if you placed something at the wrong place?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        text
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, in my advice import the script before the body end tag instead of the head tag.

Comment: I already solved the problem. I changed the [JS code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/#triggers) to this:
https://gist.github.com/MakufonSkifto/362c3a26470fd8d13a89c8e6eac2d345